# The user name or password is incorrect error while joining Windows domain

Tags: active-directory, domain, windows-server-2012-r2

I am trying to add an second domain controller (DC) to my domain. The server is running Windows Server 2012 R2. After getting the error when promoting it to an domain controller I tried uninstalling the AD DS role and joining the domain as you would do with an regular computer/server. I got the same error there to.

The error I get is: 
"The following error occurred attempting to join the domain "example.com". The user name or password is incorrect.".

I did join one other server to the  domain with the same user and the same password and I am sure that I type the correct password. I've also tried to copy the password from Notepad into the password field. I am able to sign in to the other DC with the same username and password. The account that I am using is the built in Administrator account.

My question is how I should fix the error saying that I use the wrong user name or password.

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly? To build are forest maybe? Or do a LB setup? You might want to look at [this](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj574105.aspx) if it is a forest you want.

Comment: Try qualifying the Domain Admin's credentials during the join. e.g. instead of `parentdomain\Administrator` try `parentdomain.example.com\Administrator` or the UPN `Administrator@parentdomain.example.com`.

Comment: @jscott I will try that later. I did by mistake crash my DC1 so I need to restart it physicaly.That can't be done until next week.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The account that I am using is the built in Administrator account.

You have to use an account which is part of the `Domain Admin` group to join a client to your domain. Also make sure the DNS settings on the client are correct.

Comment: The account is in the Domain Admins group and the DNS settings is pointing at the first DC.

Comment: Anything in the Event Logs from your client and DC? First DC is also your DNS server?

Answer (score 1):

I spent hours on this issue. The strange thing is that in the past I had already added tens of machins and it just worked.

But I finally found [this jscott's comment](https://serverfault.com/questions/671553/the-user-name-or-password-is-incorrect-error-while-joining-windows-domain#comment821606_671553). Credit to him.

**Using `Administrator@domain.com` worked for me.**

Neither `domain\Administrator` nor `domain.com\Administrator` had any effect though.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have joined the server to the domain as a domain member and rebooted before trying to promote it to a Domain Controller.

Answer (score 0):

Also, try on the machine itself when you try to join it rather than RDP.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is very old, but it's one of the first Google results for this problem.

For me the issue was both my domain controllers had a second, conflicting IP address. Once I removed these from the network adapter I could successfully join the second machine to the domain.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://serverfault.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://serverfault.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://serverfault.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/501368)

Comment: How does it not answer the question? I had exactly this issue - an incorrect username/password error when attempting to join a second domain controller to an existing one - and the issue was because the network adapters on both machines had a second, duplicate IP address associated with them (probably a result of the VM template they were built off). Was the issue I didn't give enough detail in my answer, because the answer is certainly correct?

Answer (score 0):

Just found another possible reason for this behaviour. We have a domain called 'ourdomain.local' and I added the new server to this domain, using the full name 'ourdomain.local' which worked fine.
But then the dcpromo-wizard does state the wrong username or password.

After taking out the server from the domain and adding it again, using this time only the domainname 'ourdomain' without the '.local'-part, everything including dcpromo worked fine.